# Vim: copy a word any number of words away

Tags: vim, insert, copy, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Just supposing the cursor is at the underscore '_':

```
line one function Abracadabrabrabra() = {
    line two stuff _
    line three more longWordIdoNotWantToType
}
```

And I want to insert Abracadabrabrabra, or maybe longWordIdoNotWantToType, or both, is there some way I can do it like this: execute a magic key command, and then press forward or backwards to cycle through the words that are nearby until I get the word I'm interested in, then press enter to insert that word.

Any other techniques that may be just as fast and flexible would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course, type the two or three first characters and press `<C-x><C-n>` (completion from the current buffer) or `<C-n>` (completion from many sources).

See `:help ins-completion`.

Comment: [`:h 24.3`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_24.html#24.3) introduces `CTRL-P` as the default completion shortcut. `CTRL-P` looks for completion candidates _before_ the cursor, and that's where I've often found the word I need is most likely to be.